Azure waf custom terraform configuration is throwing error for match_variables
I'm adding waf configuration to avoid when ever "--BEGIN PUBLIC KEY---" is matching but terraform is throwing error about some required options
  name                = "example-wafpolicy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = "Global"

  custom_rules {
    name     = "MatchPublicKey"
    priority = 1
    rule_type = "MatchRule"
    action   = "Block"

    match_conditions {
      match_variable = "RequestBody"
      operator       = "RegexMatch"
      match_values   = ["--BEGIN PUBLIC KEY---"]
    }
  }

  managed_rules {
    managed_rule_set {
      version = "1.1"
    }
  }
}```

```Too few blocks specified for "match_variables": At least 1 block(s) are expected for "match_variables"Terraform
Unexpected attribute: An attribute named "match_variable" is not expected hereTerraform


refer: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/web_application_firewall_policy for how to pass match_variables instead of match_variable @saikumar


Azure waf custom policy configuration is throwoing error for match_variables using terraform

As per the latest terraform registry you should mention the match_variables within match_conditions and use the variable_name attribute instead of match_variable
Demo configuration:
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name                              = "vinaycdnfdwafpolicy"
  resource_group_name               = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name                          = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_profile.example.sku_name
  enabled                           = true
  mode                              = "Prevention"
  redirect_url                      = "https://www.contoso.com"
  custom_block_response_status_code = 403
  custom_block_response_body        = "PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkZXI+PHRpdGxlPkhlbGxvPC90aXRsZT48L2hlYWRlcj4KPGJvZHk+CkhlbGxvIHdvcmxkCjwvYm9keT4KPC9odG1sPg=="

  custom_rule {
    name                           = "Rule1"
    enabled                        = true
    priority                       = 1
    rate_limit_duration_in_minutes = 1
    rate_limit_threshold           = 10
    type                           = "MatchRule"
    action                         = "Block"

    match_condition {
      match_variable     = "RemoteAddr"
      operator           = "IPMatch"
      negation_condition = false
      match_values       = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.0.0/24"]
    }
  }

  custom_rule {
    name                           = "Rule2"
    enabled                        = true
    priority                       = 2
    rate_limit_duration_in_minutes = 1
    rate_limit_threshold           = 10
    type                           = "MatchRule"
    action                         = "Block"

    match_condition {
      match_variable     = "RemoteAddr"
      operator           = "IPMatch"
      negation_condition = false
      match_values       = ["192.168.1.0/24"]
    }

    match_condition {
      match_variable     = "RequestHeader"
      selector           = "UserAgent"
      operator           = "Contains"
      negation_condition = false
      match_values       = ["windows"]
      transforms         = ["Lowercase", "Trim"]
    }
  }

  managed_rule {
    type    = "DefaultRuleSet"
    version = "1.0"
    action  = "Block"

    exclusion {
      match_variable = "QueryStringArgNames"
      operator       = "Equals"
      selector       = "not_suspicious"
    }

    override {
      rule_group_name = "PHP"

      rule {
        rule_id = "933100"
        enabled = false
        action  = "Block"
      }
    }

    override {
      rule_group_name = "SQLI"

      exclusion {
        match_variable = "QueryStringArgNames"
        operator       = "Equals"
        selector       = "really_not_suspicious"
      }

      rule {
        rule_id = "942200"
        action  = "Block"

        exclusion {
          match_variable = "QueryStringArgNames"
          operator       = "Equals"
          selector       = "innocent"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  managed_rule {
    type    = "Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet"
    version = "1.0"
    action  = "Log"
  }
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_firewall_policy

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_firewall_policy
need follow this doc for the solution.
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_firewall_policy" "example" 


is the correct resource to use

Have you resolved the issue since you dont mention the resoucre requrie the tried the mentioned one so can you please confirm have you resolved the issue with the link you shared  @saikumar

Yes I'm able to resolve by using the above resource group

I updated my solution as per the requriement please check

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
